# How to save a grammar rule setting that I have ignored and use it for all my future documents in Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word, spell-check, grammar

Being a JavaScript developer, recent days I am in a habit of writing words with spaces on both  ends of a bracket.
An example - ( Stack Overflow is great )

This makes it more readable for me.

I am trying to relate the same in Microsoft Word i.e. I always want to put a space after the opening and before the closing of the bracket. 
Now MSWord gives me a grammar error with green underline which I can of course ignore by clicking the 'ignore rule' option but I don't want to do it every time for all my new documents.

Just looking for a way if this is possible to save this 'ignore rule' option for all of my  future documents so that I don't have to repeat it every time.

A screenshot of same is attached for more details.[image: Ignore Rule for MS Word]

Answer (score 1):

Great question.

My first thought would be to suggest disabling the grammar check as you type:

[image: How to disable grammar checking whilst typing.]

Go to the MS Word `Options` screen, select `Proofing` and scroll down a little to reach this option; uncheck the box and press `OK`.  This will disable the annoying green line that always appears:

[image: With grammar-checking-whilst-typing disabled.]

I have shown formatting marks so that you can clearly see the spaces at either side of the bracketed section, plus also included some (horrendous and cringeworthy) grammatical errors to show how this works.

This way, you can type what you like and the grammar will be ignored.  The only warning I would issue would be to keep an eye out for any unintentional grammar mistakes if you are working on something important!

Comment: Thanks for providing an answer. This has been here for some months and nobody provided any answer. The only problem as you already mentioned will be all grammar rules will be ignored and not just the specific one. Thanks again and of course +1 for the answer.

Comment: You're most welcome; this is the first time that I have seen this question and am very surprised that nobody else had even attempted an answer!  Thanks for the +1; if it has helped/resolved your issue, then would you mind kindly selecting it as your chosen answer?

Comment: Sure @SnookerFan. I would just like to wait a little more time if someone can provide a solution which only stops the specific grammar rule and not all rules. Otherwise of course I will select yours as my answer in some time.

Answer (score 0):

In Oz we sometimes use the word "staff" instead of the word personnel. Accordingly I would use the words "staff are" in a sentence, but Word expected the word "staff" to be a singular word and expected "staff is" or "staffs are".

I found a solution.

For Word 2010, you can add a word or words that are not to be checked again by language tools by going to File>Options>Proofing>Auto Correct Options>Exceptions. Select the "Other Corrections" tab. Type in the text you no longer want checked in the "Don't Correct" box and "add" it. Click on "OK" several times to exit and remember to save the document while closing it.

Hope it works for you too!